# C# - Same button but return different value

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, button, gridview

Currently I have the outcome below:

[image]

When I press 'Send Request' button for Group 1 it stores the value of Group 2 into the database. Its suppose to store the values of Group 1 such as group number and full name. I think I got the looping wrong. Anyone willing to assist me?

Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invite invite = new Invite();
            List<Invite> inviteList = new List<Invite>();
            InviteManager inviteManager = new InviteManager();
            SystemUser account = new SystemUser();
            SystemUserManager accountManager = new SystemUserManager();
            List<Project> projectList = new List<Project>();
            ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();
            Group group = new Group();
            Group groupX = new Group();
            List<Group> groupList = new List<Group>();
            List<Group> groupListX = new List<Group>();
            List<Group> groupListY = new List<Group>();
            GroupManager groupManager = new GroupManager();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SystemUser accountA = new SystemUser();
            SystemUser accountB = new SystemUser();
            bool status = false;
            string emailAddress;

            try
            {
                groupList = groupManager.getAvailableGroup();

                if (groupList.Count == 0)
                {
                    divMessage.InnerHtml = "There is no available groups.";
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < groupList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        group = groupList[i];

                        Label lblOne = new Label();
                        lblOne.Text = "Group No.: " + group.groupNo + "</br>Group Leader: " + group.userName + "</br>Group Members:</br>";
                        form1.Controls.Add(lblOne);

                        groupListX = groupManager.getGroupMember(group.groupNo);

                        GridView grdMember = new GridView();
                        grdMember.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                        BoundField btnFAdmissionNo = new BoundField();
                        btnFAdmissionNo.HeaderText = "Admission No";
                        btnFAdmissionNo.DataField = "userAdminNo";
                        grdMember.Columns.Add(btnFAdmissionNo);

                        BoundField btnFFullName = new BoundField();
                        btnFFullName.HeaderText = "Full Name";
                        btnFFullName.DataField = "userName";
                        grdMember.Columns.Add(btnFFullName);

                        grdMember.DataSource = groupListX;
                        grdMember.DataBind();
                        form1.Controls.Add(grdMember);

                        Label lblTwo = new Label();
                        lblTwo.Text = "Project selection:</br>";
                        form1.Controls.Add(lblTwo);

                        groupListY = groupManager.getGroupChoice(group.groupNo);

                        GridView grdProjectSelection = new GridView();
                        grdProjectSelection.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                        BoundField btnFFirstChoice = new BoundField();
                        btnFFirstChoice.HeaderText = "First Choice";
                        btnFFirstChoice.DataField = "firstChoiceX";
                        grdProjectSelection.Columns.Add(btnFFirstChoice);

                        BoundField btnFSecondChoice = new BoundField();
                        btnFSecondChoice.HeaderText = "Second Choice";
                        btnFSecondChoice.DataField = "secondChoicex";
                        grdProjectSelection.Columns.Add(btnFSecondChoice);

                        BoundField btnFThirdChoice = new BoundField();
                        btnFThirdChoice.HeaderText = "Third Choice";
                        btnFThirdChoice.DataField = "thirdChoiceX";
                        grdProjectSelection.Columns.Add(btnFThirdChoice);

                        BoundField btnFForthChoice = new BoundField();
                        btnFForthChoice.HeaderText = "Forth Choice";
                        btnFForthChoice.DataField = "forthChoiceX";
                        grdProjectSelection.Columns.Add(btnFForthChoice);

                        grdProjectSelection.DataSource = groupListY;
                        grdProjectSelection.DataBind();
                        form1.Controls.Add(grdProjectSelection);

                        Button btnSendRequest = new Button();
                        btnSendRequest.Text = "Send Request";
                        btnSendRequest.Click += delegate
                        {
                            emailAddress = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

                            groupX = groupManager.getGroupLeader(group.groupNo);
                            accountB = accountManager.getAccInfoByAdminNo(groupX.userAdminNo);

                            invite.senderEmailAddress = emailAddress;
                            invite.groupNo = groupX.groupNo;
                            invite.userName = accountB.userName;
                            invite.userAdminNo = Convert.ToString(accountB.userAdminNo);
                            invite.recipientEmailAddress = accountB.recipientEmailAddress;

                            status = inviteManager.sendInvite(invite);
                        };
                        form1.Controls.Add(btnSendRequest);

                        Label lblThree = new Label();
                        lblThree.Text = "</br></br>";
                        form1.Controls.Add(lblThree);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                divMessage.InnerHtml = "Unable to retrieve data. Please contact administrator if the problem persists.";
            }
        }
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate you are using the group variable that is declared outside your for loop. This is why it is containing always the last entry of your groupList.
So instead of

```
group = groupList[i];
```

do

```
Group group = groupList[i];
```